# Capturing a value of input type"month" before submitting form

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

What I'm trying to accomplish is where when the user clicks on the input field and selects a month the page sends that data to my controller so it then can reload the page with the data that ties to that date.

I have looked into utilizing a formmethod, but that didn't seem like the right option for this issue.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
<table>
<tr>
<th>Monthly Expense Summary</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="month" name="expenseDate" id="expense"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
}
```

The expected result would be that I could access the input tag prior to the form being posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use onchange event like so `onchange="myFunction()"` where myFunction is Java Script function that calls your controller e.g

```
<script>

function myFunction()
{
   var month = document.getElementById("inputFieldID").value;
   $.ajax({
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: '/ControllerName/ActionName',
            data: { parameterNameFromControllerAction : month },
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (formData) {
                // fill form data here
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Error!');
            }
        });

}


</script>
```

Comment: Thank you I didn't think about that. I combined the use of the onchange with the hidden field to store my variable.